# What is the probability that an object thrown onto the coordinate plane passes over an integer point?

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

If an object/shape lands randomly on the Cartesian plane, what is the probability that it passes over a point in which both the x and y coordinates are integers?

Since a unit square is guaranteed to pass over such a point no matter where it lands, **will it be equal to the maximum area of a unit square covered by the object**?

I know if we take for example a circle of radius $\frac14$ this is true (the probability is $\frac\pi{16}$) by a different method, and was wondering if it generalizes to this.

Comment: No, your conjecture can't be right (if I have understood it correctly). If we make the object sufficiently long and thin, we can get the probability as close to $1$ as we like, but the maximum area of a unit square covered by the object can be as small as we like.

Comment: @TonyK I don't understand.  If the object is long and thin, doesn't the probability get close to $0$?

Comment: @TonyK that would imply that a two variable linear equation always has integer solutions

Comment: @Tavish right, that's what got me to think this might work; however, maybe something like a donut shape may disprove this?

Comment: No it wouldn't. Consider a rectangle with width $\epsilon$ and length $1/\epsilon^2$, for some small $\epsilon$. Its area is $1/\epsilon$, which we can make as large as we like by making $\epsilon$ small enough. So if we drop this on the plane with a random orientation, it is very likely (but not certain!) to cover an integer point.

Comment: @TonyK Such a rectangle is essentially an infinite random line of the form $y=mx+c$. This passes through a lattice point iff $y=mx+c$ has integer solutions.

Comment: @Tavish: nonsense. It has finite width and length, and a large area.

Comment: @TonyK It does *approach* a line.

Comment: @Tavish: A line has zero area. The difference is crucial.

Comment: @TonyK Right now what you’re saying seems nonsensical. Can you prove that the probability approaches $1$?

Comment: @Tavish: Fix the width of the rectangle to be $\epsilon > 0$. If $\tan\theta$ is irrational, where $\theta$ is the angle that the long axis of the rectangle makes with the positive $x$-axis, then we can always make the rectangle long enough that it covers a lattice point. And the probability that $\tan\theta$ is irrational is $1$. This is not quite a proof, because the required length depends on $\theta$; but it should be enough to at least make you think.

Comment: @TonyK Why can we make it long enough such that it covers a lattice point? Suppose $\theta=60^\circ$ and the rectangle passes through a rational point $(r_1,r_2)$. How long must it be?

Comment: @Tavish: that depends on $\epsilon$, obviously. But I've had enough of this for now.

Comment: @TonyK Alright, but my question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

Another counterxample: for any (big) $A$ and any (small) $\epsilon >0$ you can find $r$ s.t. the annulus between concentric circles of radius $r$ and $r+\epsilon$ is $A$.

Asymptotically, the number of lattice points included in that annulus (assuming a random center) is a Poisson random variable with mean $A$ ([eg](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06889.pdf)). Hence the probability that it includes some lattice point tends to $1- e^{-A}$.